# How to run parse_args() in jupyter notebook? Gettiing the error SystemExit: 2

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, spyder, argparse

I'm trying to do [this Gooey GUI tutorial:](https://pbpython.com/pandas-gui.html) and I literally can't get past the first block of code where he parses the arguments. I've tried Spyder and Jupyter and have been stuck at this block for an hour:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

parser = ArgumentParser(description='Create Quarterly Marketing Report')
parser.add_argument('data_directory',
                        action='store',
                        help="Source directory that contains Excel files")
parser.add_argument('output_directory',
                        action='store',
                        help="Output directory to save summary report")
parser.add_argument('cust_file',
                        action='store',
                        help='Customer Account Status File')
parser.add_argument('-d', help='Start date to include')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

My error:

```
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [-d D]
                             data_directory output_directory cust_file
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: the following arguments are required: data_directory, output_directory, cust_file
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2
```

Full Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SystemExit                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-28f93e96a3df> in <module>
----> 1 args = parser.parse_args('')

~\Anaconda3\lib\argparse.py in parse_args(self, args, namespace)
   1747     # =====================================
   1748     def parse_args(self, args=None, namespace=None):
-> 1749         args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)
   1750         if argv:
   1751             msg = _('unrecognized arguments: %s')

~\Anaconda3\lib\argparse.py in parse_known_args(self, args, namespace)
   1779         # parse the arguments and exit if there are any errors
   1780         try:
-> 1781             namespace, args = self._parse_known_args(args, namespace)
   1782             if hasattr(namespace, _UNRECOGNIZED_ARGS_ATTR):
   1783                 args.extend(getattr(namespace, _UNRECOGNIZED_ARGS_ATTR))

~\Anaconda3\lib\argparse.py in _parse_known_args(self, arg_strings, namespace)
   2014         if required_actions:
   2015             self.error(_('the following arguments are required: %s') %
-> 2016                        ', '.join(required_actions))
   2017 
   2018         # make sure all required groups had one option present

~\Anaconda3\lib\argparse.py in error(self, message)
   2499         self.print_usage(_sys.stderr)
   2500         args = {'prog': self.prog, 'message': message}
-> 2501         self.exit(2, _('%(prog)s: error: %(message)s\n') % args)

~\Anaconda3\lib\argparse.py in exit(self, status, message)
   2486         if message:
   2487             self._print_message(message, _sys.stderr)
-> 2488         _sys.exit(status)
   2489 
   2490     def error(self, message):

SystemExit: 2
```

I have checked this error on Stack Overflow but the suggetsed answers didn't work for me or didn't go into enough detail for me to figure out the problem.

I know this is supposed to be used in the command line, but is there any way to follow the above tutorial in Jupyter or Spyder?

edit: not sure if this is any help, but the output of `sys.argv`:

```
['C:\\Users\\s\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\ipykernel_launcher.py',
 '-f',
 'C:\\Users\\s\\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\runtime\\kernel-cc697613-14f5-4979-a353-6112886aba45.json']
```

Comment: Don't try to run this tutorial in a notebook.  It's not intended for that environment.

Comment: It doesn't work in Spyder either. What do you recommend? Getting the same error in VSCode too.

Comment: No. How would I do it in this case?

Comment: Spyder: "Run" menu, "Configuration per file", enable and fill "Command line options". But generally speaking if you want to follow a tutorial, you should do what the tutorial says. It does not say you need Jupyter or Spyder, it just links a notebook which shows the steps going to be packed into a standalone Python file. But the notebook itself does not try to parse command line arguments exactly because there are no command line arguments in notebooks.

Comment: So I should just copy and paste the code into a text file, save it as .py and run it? And I have to save the text file then run it from the command line every time I want to tweak something?

Comment: A tutorial about command line arguments, with passing mention of notebooks.  https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/argument-parsing-in-python

Comment: When using a notebook, you can set various parameter values directly - either in a cell or with some widget.  When running a script from shell, you often want to set, or tweak, some values when you start it.  As the tutorial says, you use commandline arguments when you use basic linux commands like `ls`.  These arguments are for developed, running, code, not for interactive development.

Answer (score 0):

In a notebook or interactive session you can test the `argparse` setup with

```
args = parser.parse_args('dir1 dir2 foobar'.split())
print(args)
```

`parse_args()` parses the `sys.argv[1:]` list, which comes from the shell command.  To look at it use:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

Most likely you'll see strings that are relevant to the `jupyter` server.

When you provide a list, it's parsed rather than the default.

You can even use `args = argparse.Namespace(foo='bar', x=2)`.  `args` just needs to have the attributes that the rest of code expects.